# Making text output dynamic using ofstream

Tags: ofstream

I'm trying to create a program that outputs the vin, gallons, miles, and mpg of a car to a text file using ofstream.

```
outfile << setw(8) << "VIN" << setw(19) << "Miles" << setw(10) << "Gallons" << setw(6) << "MPG"      << "\n" << "---------------------------------------------\n" << vin(0) << setw(10) << miles(0) << setw(6) << gallons(0) << setw(11) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1) << static_cast<double>(miles(0))/gallons(0)<< "\n" << vin(1) << setw(10) << miles(1) << setw(6) << gallons(1) << setw(11) << static_cast<double>(miles(1))/gallons(1) << "\n" << vin(2) << setw(10) << miles(2) << setw(6) << gallons(2) << setw(11) << static_cast<double>(miles(2))/gallons(2) << "\n" << vin(3) << setw(10) << miles(3) << setw(6) << gallons(3) << setw(11) << static_cast<double>(miles(3))/gallons(3) << "\n" << vin(4) << setw(10) << miles(4) << setw(6) << gallons(4) << setw(11) << static_cast<double>(miles(4))/gallons(4) << endl;
```

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this without having to repeat for each new row? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first, you should object-orient your code to keep it concise. This means by preference keeping the vin, gallons, miles, and mpg as data members of a class.

```c++
struct Car
{
    // ...
    int vin, gallons, miles, mpg;
};
```

Then you can implement stream inserters/extractors for input and output. Create and put your `Car` elements in a `std::vector<Car>` and iterate through them to read or write them to standard input/output.

Ultimately, the line above should be transformed into:

```c++
for (const auto& c : cars)
{
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```